# Can't add one node to another

Tags: java, android, xml, nodes

I have two Nodes `node1` and `nod2` which have different parent documents, now I want to call

`node1.appendChild(node2);`

function for this nodes but my application crashes, below you can see owner documents and XMLs of nodes.

```
Document document1 = node1.getOwnerDocument();
Document document2 = node2.getOwnerDocument();
```

Both nodes have different owner documents. `node1` owner document described below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientGetOTPSeedMessage>
    <UserID>userID</UserID>
    <DeviceInfo/>
</ClientGetOTPSeedMessage>
```

and `node2` owner document is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Desc>
    <Desc1>First name</Desc1>
    <Desc2>Second name</Desc2>
</Desc>
```

Now I want to get `</Desc>` node from `document2` and put it to `<DeviceInfo/>` node in the `document1` how I can do it. And I want to say that `node1` and `node2` keep the nodes which I want to add one to another, but when I write

```
node1.appendChild(node2);
```

my application crashes, I guess the main reason is that they have different owner documents.

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/ see news parser...

Comment: @SamirMangroliya sorry but this article is not useful in my case, I can't find answer on my question.

Comment: you have to maintain dynamic array  first get data from both document add it in one dynamic array

Comment: But I have Nodes with that data, I just want to `node1.appendChild(node2);` add one node to another, why can't I do it ?

Comment: Look I have two nodes `node1` and `node2` which have different parent documents, now I want to call `node1.appendChild(node2);` but my application crashes, why @SamirMangroliya ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the application crashes is, as you said,the different owner documents (see [**this**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) for more details). To solve the problem you should import node2 in document1, like this:

```
n2 = document1.importNode(n2, true);
```

and then:

```
 n1.appendChild(n2);
```

More info about import [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29).